# how to restore link between torrent and file?

Tags: bittorrent, restore, transmission

I have several files downloaded with the Transmission bittorrent client. But for certain reasons (e.g. OS re-installation) these files have "lost" their torrents. How can I restore them, so that these files are available for upload again?
SW versions used: Transmission ver. 2.82, Linux Mint 17.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the torrent again to Transmission and set the location as the same as before. The client will automatically check the file's downloaded pieces.